# awk columnwise sum a particular group

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, scripting

I am new to shell scripting.I have a CSV file and i want to print column wise sum of rows that match some condition

```
column1   column2   column3   column4 column5.......    columnN
a1         b1        c1       0.5      50                100

a2         b2        c2       1       25                150

a1         b1        c2       0.5      25                 10

a2         b2        c2      2        20                100
```

(assuming comma as separator
i can SUM a particular column by

```
 awk -F ',' '{ x = x + $4 } END { print x }'
```

1) How can i use it in a loop from kth to Nth to sum columns with numeric values?

2)Also how can i use it conditionally only to sum columns of rows that match some condition
say,column2 is b2 and column3 is c2?
I can do

```
  cat file| grep b2 |grep c2| awk...as answer to 1st question
```

but it would be very naive .Can you please help me with above two queries?

Based on answers below i tried

```
awk -F’,' -v k=“3" -v n=“6" '$2=="b2" && $3="c2"{for(i=k;i<=n;i++)s[i]+=$i} 
        END{for(x in s)printf "sum of column %d is %s\n",x,s[x]}’ test.csv
```

but it gives syntax error

```
 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `i=k'
```

Comment: You have characters in your command that look like singe and double quotes but aren't: `’` vs `'`and `“` vs `"`.

Comment: The error message was misleading.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can combine two conditions: (`$2 == "b2" && $3 == "c2"`) and (`from kth - nth columns`)

```
awk -F'whatever' -v k="$k" -v n="$n" 
                '$2=="b2" && $3="c2"{for(i=k;i<=n;i++)s[i]+=$i}
                END{for(x in s)printf "sum of column %d is %s\n", x,s[x]}' file
```

in above codes:

- `-F'whatever'` is the column separator
- `-v k="$k" -v n="$n"` `k and n` are the column range. You can hard code them or use shell variables: `$k/$n`
- output will be something like:

  ```
  sum of column 3 is 300
  sum of column 4 is 400
  ```
- and the codes were not tested

Comment: I tried it as posted in my question but it gives syntax error near i=k

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not comma separated, its tab or space, so you do not need the `-F`
This may do:

```
awk '$2=="b2" && $3=="c2" {x+=$4} END {print x}' file
```

This will if `column 2` is `b2` and `column 3` is `c2`, then sum `column 4` and print value.

Comment: how to use a loop in it ..if i put for loop just before x+= as in another answer I get a syntax error

Comment: @bl3e I do not understand what you like to loop.  This solution loops trough all the line, one by one, test, and add if ok.

Comment: by loop i meant to sum all columns..not just 4th.The error was due to special characters

Comment: You can do like this: change `{x+=$4}` to `{for (i=4;i<=8;i++) x+=$i}`.  It will then sum all columns from `4` to `8` on all lines.